# Writing a byte array to local disk fails in SL 4

Tags: security, silverlight-4.0

I get a bytearray from the server which I want to write to my local disk. It's a spreadsheet and it's part of an export function.

This is what I do on the client:

```
Using oFileStream As New FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)
    oFileStream.Write(excel, 0, excel.Length)
End Using
```

This is the error occuring on creating a new Filestream:

[image]

Btw: I know there are several threads about this issue, but none resolved my problem.

Comment: Basically Silverlight apps don't have access to the filesystem. In other words, you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the byte array on the server and provide a link to it on the client. That way, your client (SL) won't need to write anything.